# dual database compare and update inventory value zencart stock function

Tags: php, mysql, database

Things get lost or broken, so basically, what I want to do is to compare actual inventory database against zencart store stock and update zencart stock if it is greater than the real inventory database.

I have a table 'products' in my first database (zencart) and second database (inventory), like this:
    products_id    products_model    products_quantity

```
zencart.products :
products_id : 3 | products_model : J293-04 | products_quantity : 4 | 
[...]

inventory.products :
products_id : 15 | products_model : J293-04 | products_quantity : 1 | 
[...]
```

The inventory.products database is the actual count of the products available.

When the zencart stock query function tests if goods are available,
I want it to compare stock quantity with the inventory database.
If the zencart stock quantity is > than inventory stock, then
update zencart stock quantity to = inventory stock.

The zencart stock functions use zencart.products.product_id
so the zencart.products.products_model has to be used to compare the 2 databases.

This is what I have come up replace the zencart stock count function.  It seems to be overly complex, and I am not sure if a inventory global $db2; needs to be put in.

```
function zen_get_products_stock($products_id) {
global $db;
$products_id = zen_get_prid($products_id);

$stock_query = "select products_quantity
                from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . "
                where products_id = '" . (int)$products_id . "'";
$stock_model_query = "select products_model
                from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . "
                where products_id = '" . (int)$products_id . "'";

$inv_stock_query = "select products_quantity
                from inventory.products.products_model
                where zencart.products.products_model =
                      inventory.products.products_model

if $stock_query > $inv_stock_query 
{
   $stock_query = $inv_stock_query
   UPDATE 
   inventory.products, 
   zencart.products 
   SET 
   zencart.products.products_quantity = inventory.products.products_quantity
   WHERE 
   zencart.products.products_model = inventory.products.model
}

$stock_values = $db->Execute($stock_query);

return $stock_values->fields['products_quantity'];
}
```

Original code from  zencart/includes/functions/functions_lookups.com

```
/**
 * Return a product's stock count.
 *
 * @param int The product id of the product who's stock we want
*/
  function zen_get_products_stock($products_id) {
    global $db;
    $products_id = zen_get_prid($products_id);
    $stock_query = "select products_quantity
                from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . "
                where products_id = '" . (int)$products_id . "'";

$stock_values = $db->Execute($stock_query);

return $stock_values->fields['products_quantity'];
}

/**
 * Check if the required stock is available.
 *
 * If insufficent stock is available return an out of stock message
 *
 * @param int The product id of the product whos's stock is to be checked
 * @param int Is this amount of stock available
 *
 * @TODO naughty html in a function
*/
function zen_check_stock($products_id, $products_quantity) {
$stock_left = zen_get_products_stock($products_id) - $products_quantity;
$out_of_stock = '';

if ($stock_left < 0) {
  $out_of_stock = '<span class="markProductOutOfStock">' . STOCK_MARK_PRODUCT_OUT_OF_STOCK . '</span>';
}

return $out_of_stock;
  }
```

Thank you for your help.